# lastConnectedWatch() of PBPebbleCentral returns always nil?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pebble-watch

I'm currently building a watchapp for Pebble which will have to communicate with one Swift app. I've implemented all the needed functions but every time I try to get the last connected Pebble  from PBPebbleCentral I receive nil. This happens despite the fact that my Pebble is connected with the iPhone and I have PebbleKit and PebbleVendor correctly imported.
I'm using Pebble with firmware v2.7 and iPhone 5s running iOS 8.0.2. Further I have based my two apps on the weather-app example provided by Pebble.

```
 defaultCentral.delegate = self
 setTargetWatch(defaultCentral.lastConnectedWatch())
```

Comment: Did you include the ExternalAccessory framework and listed the `com.getpebble.public` string in `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols`? (cf http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/mobile-apps/ios/ios-install)

Comment: Yes, I've done everything described in developer.getpebble.com and checked it twice. I rewrote the app in objective C and it worked fine. I still can't find what's wrong in the Swift version.

Answer (score 0):

I found **my mistake**! I used to receive nil from lastConnectedWatch() because I'd initialized defaultCentral incorrectly.

My old code was:

```
let defaultCentral: PBPebbleCentral = PBPebbleCentral()
defaultCentral.delegate = self
setTargetWatch(defaultCentral.lastConnectedWatch())
```

And the correct code is:

```
let defaultCentral: PBPebbleCentral = PBPebbleCentral.defaultCentral()
defaultCentral.delegate = self
setTargetWatch(defaultCentral.lastConnectedWatch())
```